# Highcharts reload json data

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have a Highcharts column chart which gets its data from the file data.php (JSON data). Every minute I want it to reload data.php into the chart. Animation is not necessary.

Can anyone help me out? Current code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container2',
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
            text: 'Gemiddele reactietijd laatste 30 runs'
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Milliseconden'
        }

    },
    exporting: {
     enabled: false
    },  
     credits: {
          enabled: false
      },
    xAxis: {
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        minorTickLength: 0,
        tickLength: 0
    },
     plotOptions: {
            column: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    rotation: -90,
                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                    align: 'right',
                    x: 4,
                    y: 10,
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '13px',
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
                        textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                    },
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.y+' ms';
                    },

                },
                animation: false,
                enableMouseTracking: false,

            }
        },
    series: [{}]
};

$.getJSON('data.php', function(data) {
    options.series[0].data = data;
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});


});
```

I tried adding this at the very end of the script, but it does not work:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
 $.getJSON('data.php', function(data) {
        options.series[0].data = data;
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Try to put options variable inside `getJSON()` callback. If this won't help, let us know what error do you have in JS console.

Comment: Hi Pawel, can you please post some code to explain what you mean? I am  just a beginner when it somes to this... Thanks for your help...

Comment: I mean to define `var options = { ... }` variable just before `options.series[0].data = data` line.

Comment: I fixed it by putting everything within the window.setInterval(function(){}. Problem now is that the chart loads  5 seconds after loading the page. How to fix this? I don't want to define the code for the chart double. In case I have to edit somthing I would have to edit it twice.

Comment: General idea is to use copy of object when creating chart, not main object. For example, go back to your first example, but in each constructor for chart use: `new Highcharts.Chart( jQuery.merge({}, options) );`.

Comment: I already fixed it. I put the code for drawing the chart and inserting data in a loadchart() function. Then I call loadchart() at page load and also every five seconds. This solution only needs me to define the code for the chart once, which is what I wanted. Thanks averyone for your efforts!